# Why is the second dialogue not opening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to use the jquery UI dialogue to create a few popups with extra information.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

If I add one dialogue it works, but the second one I add does not seem to work.

I tried a few things but I must be overlooking something.

To test it I also modified the example file of Jquery UI and also there the second dialogue does not show up.

Does anybody have some good tips for me?

The original files can be downloaded from http://jqueryui.com/download/

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 400,
  buttons: [{
    text: "Ok",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }, {
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }]
});

// Link to open the dialog
$("#dialog-link").click(function(event) {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  event.preventDefault();
});

$("#dialog2").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 400,
  buttons: [{
    text: "Ok",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }, {
    text: "Cancel",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }]
});

// Link to open the dialog
$("#dialog-link2").click(function(event) {
  $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 62.5%"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
}
.demoHeaders {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
#dialog-link {
  padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
#dialog-link span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
#icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
#icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
}
.fakewindowcontain .ui-widget-overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>
<p><a href="#" id="dialog-link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span  class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a>
</p>

<h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog2</h2>
<p><a href="#" id="dialog-link2" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a>
</p>

<!-- ui-dialog -->
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
  <p>number 1</p>
</div>

<!-- ui-dialog -->
<div id="dialog1" title="Dialog Title">
  <p>number 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The ID is `dialog1`, yet you’re trying to address `dialog2` in your jQuery. Voting to close as off-topic due to typo.

Comment: Sure. I see your point. My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add a second dialog - just use `$('#divID').html()` to change the content in the existing one.

You *do* need two triggers, two buttons -- but you can use just one dialog to display both dialog-fulls of content. Here's an example:

```js
$('#dlgDIV').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 200,
      width: 350,
      modal: true
});

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
   $('#dlgDIV').html('Here is some stuff').dialog('open');
});

$('#yrbutt').click(function(){
   $('#dlgDIV').html('\
    <div class="wow">And some other stuff</div>\
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" /></div>\
  ').dialog('open');
});
```

```css
.wow{font-size:2rem;color:purple;margin:20px;border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="dlgDIV"></div>

<button id="mybutt">Click Me</button>
<button id="yrbutt">Click Me Next</button>
```

*Thanks to Andrew L for assisting with improving answer.*